# Split file .log in fields to use within a Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, file, split

Hello I have a log with this format

```
-------------------------------------------------------
==00043== Found File /home/xxx  Failed with Error FAILURE_LOG_WINEXE_IF_3276147548] Error while parsing the PE

==00044== Found File /home/glasswall  Passed

==00045== Found File /home/xxx  Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by

==00046== Found File /home/xxx  Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I want to split it in 3 fields but I didn't understand how can I do this.

I want to some like this to use in a dataframe in pandas

```
File number              Status     Description 
00043                       Failed      Error while parsing the PE 
00044                       Passed     
00045                       Failed      Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by 
00046                       Failed      Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Does your file start wit the `-----` line?

Comment: Is `failed` part of the `Description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
pd_list = []
with open("log.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        matches = re.findall(r"==(\d+)==.*(Passed|Failed.*)", line.strip(), re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
        status = matches[0][1].split()
        if len(status) > 1:
            pd_list.append([matches[0][0], status[0], matches[0][1]])
        else:
            pd_list.append([matches[0][0], status[0], ""])

x = pd.DataFrame(pd_list, columns=["File number", "Status", "Description" ])
print(x.to_string())
```

---

```
  File number  Status                    Description
0       00043  Failed    Failed with Error FAILURE_LOG_WINEXE_IF_3276147548] Error while parsing
1       00044  Passed                                                                         
2       00045  Failed    Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by
3       00046  Failed    Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/7f4f24ebcc)

Answer (score 0):

You have an interesting challenge because you have spaces used as a delimiter and spaces that belong in the description. @pedro-lobito has provided an elegant solution. Here is one that relies only upon split() and re.sub() to convert the log file. This assumes that the "Found File" always appears as it does and isn't some other value with more or fewer than 2 words.

I chose to incorporate the logfile text into the example code, but it should be read from a file in your ultimate solution.

The output file is tab-delimited. In my example, the output is printed. You could use a file write.

```
import re

logfile= """==00043== Found File /home/xxx  Failed with Error FAILURE_LOG_WINEXE_IF_3276147548] Error while parsing the PE
==00044== Found File /home/glasswall  Passed
==00045== Found File /home/xxx  Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by
==00046== Found File /home/xxx  Failed with Error CLI] File type could not be detected by"""

#print(logfile)

lines = logfile.split("\n")

print("File number\tStatus\tDescription")
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split(" ")               # split line by space delimiter
    subst = " ".join(fields[0:6])          # reconstruct string from delimited fields
    logst = fields[0]
    logst = re.sub("=", "", logst)         # replace "=" with empty string
    logst = logst + "\t" + fields[5]       # log string from fields 0 and 5
    descr = re.sub(subst, "", line)        # substitute reconstructed string from line
    descr = re.sub("^ with ", "", descr)   # strip leading "with " from Description
    print(logst + "\t" + descr)
```

Output:

```
File number     Status  Description
00043   Failed  Error FAILURE_LOG_WINEXE_IF_3276147548] Error while parsing the PE
00044   Passed
00045   Failed  Error CLI] File type could not be detected by
00046   Failed  Error CLI] File type could not be detected by
```